# SSH users with ssh keys can't login to Usermin

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, password

I'm setting up a fresh Ubuntu netty 11.04 instance on AWS and needed Usermin to allow my "Ubuntu" user account to login. The problem is that the "ubuntu" user uses ssh keys to log into the server. I tried creating a new account with password and Usermin allowed it to login.

My question is, how can Usermin allow access to my "Ubuntu" user? Do I have to create a passwd for "ubuntu"? How would I do that? Does it affect my SSH login?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a password for the user `ubuntu`. When you are logged in as the user, just type `passwd` and it will ask you twice for the (new) password.

You will still be able to log in using the key.

Comment: does that require me to provide a password when using ssh?

Comment: Nothing will change for the way you log in. It gives you the opportunity to log-in with a password if you don't have your key.